# Store persistent data in node.js request

Tags: node.js, session, request, persistence

Is there a way I can persistently store an object in a node.js http request? For example, I want to define a user:

```
var user = {
    name: 'John',
    role: 'admin',
    age: '40',
    cars: {
        'Audi R8',
        'BMW i8',
        'Tesla'
    }
}
```

Then be able to call it in any http request:

```
req.data = user;
```

I understand that I can store this data in a session cookie and send it to the browser, but I'm worried that a user might tamper the data...

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Session data is not saved in the cookie itself, just the session ID. Session data is stored on server-side.

Comment: You could use *json web token*(jwt). With jwt you can send the data to browser and you would know if the user tampered the data because decoding of token would fail.